# How to merge two objects without keys which are not in the master object?

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I have 2 object "master" and "slave" (saved master before master change), when i'm load slave object i want load value from slave in master without "old" key.

```
var obj_master = {
    'key': {
        'key_1': '1',
        'key_2': '1'
    },
    'key_new': '1'
};
var obj_slave = {
    'key': {
        'key_1': '2',
        'key_2': '2'
    },
    'key_old': '2',
};
```

desired result:

```
{
'key': {
    'key': '2',
    'key_2': '2'
},
'key_new': 1
}
```

If there is a solution using lodash it would be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

var obj = Object.keys(obj_slave).filter(key => key in obj_master).forEach(key => {
obj_master[key] = obj_slave[key];
});